# RichFaces: partial form validation

Tags: validation, jsf, richfaces

I have a form containing several fields(name, surname, etc) and a datatable. Datatable is dedicated to store addresses into the backing bean. A person can have more than one address so I add a button as follows:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.addAddressRow}" value="Add address" reRender="addresses" />
```

where "addresses" is the id of my datatable. I use a4j because there's no need to refresh the page.z

What I want to do is to skip the validation of the entire form except the address fields when this button is pressed. So a user can add one more address if all the previous addresses are correctly filled. The other fields should not be validated.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your address table and the `commandButton` with `<a4j:region>` tags and set the attribute `renderRegionOnly` to `true`. 
Look at following example. Here only the last two text boxes **(txt2 and txt3)** are validated when you press the first button. If you press the second button all three text boxes are validated.

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText required="true" id="txt1"/>
  <rich:message for="txt1" style="color:red"/>

  <a4j:region renderRegionOnly="true">
      <h:inputText required="true" id="txt2"/>
      <rich:message for="txt2" style="color:red"/>
      <h:inputText required="true" id="txt3"/>
      <rich:message for="txt3" style="color:red"/>
      <a4j:commandButton value="Ok1" />
  </a4j:region>

  <a4j:commandButton value="Ok2" />
</h:form>
```